# C#- Fatal error occurred on executing command with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, fatal-error

I am try to insert data in MySQL DB with C# as a front-end. The query is running in a windows service application and the whole execution runs on thread. I am getting an error after couple of hours of the execution of the service. The service runs at an interval of 10 minutes. Suppose it has executed at 6:00 am then it will again get executed at 6:10 am in this way it moves sequentially. In each run it inserts around 50 rows in the DB.

The error which is being thrown after a couple of hour of execution is given below. It is a sample from my error log.

> MySqlException in InsertData Fatal error encountered during command
>   execution.::   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetProcedures(String[] restrictions)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetProcedures(String[]
>   restrictions)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetSchemaInternal(String
>   collection, String[] restrictions)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetSchema(String collection, String[] restrictions)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.GetSchema(String collectionName, String[] restrictionValues)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcData(MySqlConnection
>   connection, String spName)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.AddNew(MySqlConnection connection, String spName)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcedure(MySqlConnection
>   conn, String spName)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.GetParameters(String procName)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve(Boolean preparing)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at InsertData(String Name, String Info, String Output):: Inner Exception 1: Fatal error
>   encountered attempting to read the resultset.:: Inner Exception 2:
>   Reading from the stream has failed.:: Inner Exception 3: Unable to
>   read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was
>   interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.:: Inner Exception 4: A
>   blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall]

I have added inner exception up-to four levels in log so that some clues can be surfaced. The inner exceptions begin has title Inner Exception 1, Inner Exception 2 and so on.

**Below is my code.**

```
internal static int UpdateDataInToDB(DataInformation info)
{
    MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("ProcInsertData", mySqlCon);
    try
    {
        int rowCount = 0;

        mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param1", DbType.Int64).Value = info.ID;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param2", DbType.String).Value = info.Name;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param3", DbType.String).Value = info.Address;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param4", DbType.Int32).Value = info.Age;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param5", DbType.DateTime).Value = info.DOB;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Param6", DbType.Int32).Value = info.RollNo;

        mySqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
        rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());


    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        //MySqlException logging
        ResetDBConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Exception logging
    }
    finally
    {
        if (mySqlCommand != null) mySqlCommand.Dispose();
        mySqlCon.CloseConnection();
    }

return rowCount;
}
```

I haven't used any DataReader in my code, but I don't know from where this ExecuteReader is appearing the error text thrown by the code. I have set 'pooling = false' in my connection string.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which mySqlCommand object are you disposing in the finally? Because the mySqlCommand object in the try is not in scope in the finally. A using block would be easier to use here.

Comment: Sorry @Polyfun I edited my code. mySqlCommand object is outside the scope of try block. Actually, its a pseudo code, I didn't paste my actual code here, it's against my organisation's policy.

Comment: It looks like MySql.Data is failing (and I'm not quite sure why) when trying to get information about stored procedures from the database. This happens every single time you execute the stored procedure because `Pooling=false`. So you may be able to work around this by changing to `Pooling=true`.

Comment: Initially, Pooling = true was set in app.config. In that case, it was reaching to maximum pool size even though I was closing mySQL connection. I googled and found that we can avoid this by setting pooling= false. Therefore, I set it as suggested.

Comment: Can anyone have a look in the inner exceptions. The last one is Inner Exception 4: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. So, what roll this WSACancelBlockingCall playing. Why there is a blocking operation? Whether, it is for the thread operation which is being used in my application?